# Binding service in pcf and not giving configuration

Tags: spring, microservices, cloud-foundry

I have observed weird behavior in my service that is running on pcf when I just bind the service on the PCF with my micro service.

My question is, what configuration will application (Spring) be using to interact with the binding service? Just the default one, or spring will automatically detect the configurations?

Comment: Did you restage your service after binding the new service?

Comment: Yes. I restage after the changes. But question is not this.

Comment: In cloud environments, the spring profile used is `cloud`. The cloud implementation injects all necessary services details (bound services etc) in the cloud environment for your application as part of the staging process. And at runtime, your spring application will leverage it from `cloud` profile. HTH